# Libraries in render array

Tags: entities, theming

I'm trying to attach a JS library to a render array for a field formatter.

I'm using

```
  $element[$delta] = array(
    '#theme' => 'image',
    '#prefix' => "<a class='fluidbox' href='{$lightbox_path}'>",
    '#suffix' => "</a>",
    '#path' => $initial_path,
    '#alt' => $item['alt'],
    '#attached' => array(
      'libraries_load' => array(
        array('fluidbox'),
        ),
      'js' => array(
        drupal_get_path('module', 'fluidbox') . '/js/drupal_fluidbox.js',
        ),
      ),
    );
```

But the library doesn't seem to load. Any suggestions? It works if I put libraries_load into a preprocess function.